# In Python, how to slice a list to get the first element, and all elements except the last?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4,5]
```

How to get:

```
[1, 2]
[4]
```

In the above example, I know this works:

```
a[:-1]
b[:-1]
```

However, when:

```
c = [1]
c[:-1]
```

The result is an empty list.

Comment: What were you expecting instead of an empty list? All but the last element of a 1-element list means no elements.

Comment: what you expect from the last one? :)

Comment: Also, your title doesn't seem to fit your description. The first element, and all but the last, of `a` would be `1` and `[1, 2]`, but you only get the latter, and don't even mention the former.

Comment: Maybe he meant to get the first element OR all elements except the last.

Comment: @malfunctioning Maybe, but in that case you'd think he would mention it in the question. And just writing that question makes it pretty obvious that `or` or `else` can trivially do what he wants (although it may not be the clearest way to express it), and I can't imagine anyone who's learned slicing but not learned either of those...

Comment: @abamert: I understand. What I meant though, is to get "all elements except the last", except when the list has only 1 element, then return the list with the single element. JuniorCompressor's answer is doing that.

Comment: @abarnert ah, my memory is bad. I had thought in Ruby that I could do this:   `[1][0..-2]` but I was mistaken, and the effect is the same as it is in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the following code fragment:

```
c[:1] + c[1:-1]
```

For example:

```
>>> c = [1]
>>> c[:1] + c[1:-1]
[1]
```

With `c[:1]` you get a list consisting of the first element (if it exists, otherwise the empty list), and with `c[1:-1]` you get from the second  until the end except the last. If there isn't a second element `c[1:-1]` will just return the empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Following JuniorCompressor's answer, if the point is just to remove last element (keep first and if exist others also keep them, but remove last == remove last, if first element is also not the last element). Is it?

```
>>> def removelast(l):
...     if len(l)>1: del l[len(l)-1]
...     return l
>>> a = range(5)
>>> removelast(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1]
>>> removelast(b)
[1]
```

Comment: Yes that is the resulting effect, though your solution ends up changing the given list (which may or may not be desired)